# How to input a JSON file an print a line

Tags: python, json

Write a program that inputs a JSON file (format just like
example1.json) and prints out the value of the title field.

```
import json

# TODO: Read your json file here and return the contents
def read_json(filename):
    dt = {}
    # read the file and store the contents in the variable 'dt'
    with open(filename,"r") as fh:
        dt = json.load(fh)

    ###fh = open(filename, "r")
    ###dt = json.load(fh)

    return dt


# TODO: Pass the json file here and print the value of title field. Remove the `pass` statement
def print_title(dt):
    print filename["title"]


# TODO: Input a file from the user
filename = raw_input("Enter the JSON file: ")


# The function calls are already done for you
r = read_json(filename)
print_title(r)
```

Hi, I'm new with Python and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I keep getting the following message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHlNO.png)

Comment: Your traceback is *text*, please don't use a screenshot as that can't be searched or copied into an editor.

Comment: You're trying to 'print' the filename instead of the parsed data. Try replacing `print filename["title"]` with `print(dt["title"])`

Answer (score 2):

Your'e almost there, you just confused with the parameter name.

Change this:

```
def print_title(dt):
    print filename["title"]
```

To:

```
def print_title(dt):
    print dt["title"]
```

Comment: What is the difference between line 7-8 and 10-11? They both seem to do the same thing

Comment: Nvm I think I got it